# spock versus easyb

Tags: grails, easyb, spock

I just had brief looks at easyb and spock , both seem to be similar, however spock seems to be more technically oriented, is there any best practice regarding when to use which ?

For example which should one preferred for a new grails project ?
which should one preferred for a legacy java project for which automated tests just need to be written ?
is one more suited for integration tests than the other ?

Things of that sort ..

Thanks
Sudarshan

Comment: Not a real answer, that's why I'm posting as a comment. Spock seems to be much more widely used in the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Spock vs EasyB** Spock is a BDD inspired framework that gives devs tools to make their lives easier. EasyB is a great way to capture requirements and build the acceptance tests. EasyB scenarios can be stories, and can leave them blank to make them descriptive stories. Then start adding closure code and can put in selenium, etc. ([source](http://gettinggroovy.com/category/best-practices/))

While browsing the web I've seen opinions that EasyB has some usability issues that are still being puzzled out. Moreover I was able to find much more articles, tutorials, etc on Spock than EasyB which seems to be less popular.

Spock is based on JUnit so running the test cases for regular Java projects is as easy as running any regular JUnit tests, be it from an IDE or continuous integration servers. Take a look at [Testing with Spock](http://www.aqris.com/display/DEV/2010/01/19/Testing+with+Spock).

To conclude, I'd stick to Spock.

Comment: I did my own digging around and would tend to go with you.However would just want to say that the easyb commnunity on google groups is extremely helpful and prompt in answering queries.